dimension of GIT quotients
Let $X$ be a non irreducible affine variety and $G$ a linearly reductive algebraic group, acting freely on X. I have seen in several places that the dimension of the the orbit space $X/G$ (that parametrizes the closed orbits) is $dim X -dim G$. I wonder if  is there a concrete example where none of the irreducible components of X/G have the expected dimension $dim X -dim G$.

Dear @Sasha, I don't think this action is free if we don't cut out the origin, am I right?

actually, I think that if $G$ is connected, then the action of X/G will be action on each irreducible component of X, and thus the answer is true. The example should be given for a ugly group.
